# What is the source code of find element in selenium-java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This maybe a fairly simple question,but I'm having hard time finding it out.I'm trying to understand what is the source code of the find elements function in selenium-java? I looked at the source code,I only found the webdriver interface that has unimplemented function? If it is an interface it should be implemented by some class,Isn't it? but I could not find any class that implements webdriver interface.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you search manually, or did you use an IDE that searches for references? You could have even found it by searching for the string "implements WebDriver". But even better would be to import it into something like eclipse, and then use it to search for all classes that implement the interface.

Comment: @MarkLapierre, I did it manually.Could you please let me know how I can do it using eclipse?

Comment: santhosh kumar posted one option. Another is to download the source from github, import it into eclipse, and then open the type hierarchy for the webdriver interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking at the [`WebDriver` interface](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java#L49) alone. But, the main point of interest should be the [`RemoteWebDriver` class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java#L83) which implements `WebDriver`.

Note that browser-specific `WebDriver` implementations are then based on the `RemoteWebDriver`. For instance, see the [`ChromeDriver`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.java#L109).

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this same problem once a time and Eclipse is providing a plugin to attach the source to the reference library automatically.

It is called **JAVA SOURCE ATTACHER** -  http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-source-attacher It actually does what eclipse should do - a right click context menu that says "Attach Java Source".

Below is an example,

[image]

It automatically downloads the source for you and attaches it. If it's not able to find the source, then we need to attach it manually by searching the source in internet. In the case if eclipse is not able to find it, then try below site for the selenium server standalone source files=> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseleniumserversourcesjar.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the webdriver is an interface, If you want to see the implementation you should go to the webdriver implementation that you are using.

for example for firefox: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have an answer that is essentially the same as someone else's answer, please upvote their answer instead of posting your own. Feel free to answer if you have something to add that you believe previous answers are missing, or comment on their answer if you think it can be improved.